# mock object library ANY not working as expected

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I'm currently trying to mock a patch request to a server and I'm trying to make use of the ANY attribute in the mock object library. I have the following code:

```
@patch('path_to_patch.patch')
def test_job_restarted_succesfully(mock_patch):
   make_patch_call()
   mock_patch.assert_called_with(url=ANY, payload=ANY, callback=ANY, async_run=ANY, kwargs=ANY)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
AssertionError: Expected call: patch(async_run=<ANY>, callback=<ANY>, kwargs=<ANY>, payload=<ANY>, url=<ANY>)
E           Actual call: patch(async_run=True, callback=<function JobSvc.send_job_patch_request.<locals>.retry_on_404 at 0x000002752B873168>, payload={'analyzer': {'state': 'started'}, 'meta': {}}, svc_auth=UUID('40ed1a00-a51f-11eb-b1ed-b46bfc345269'), url='http://127.0.0.1:8080/rarecyte/1.0/jobs/slide1@20210422_203831_955885')
```

I found ANY in the docs given below and can't figure out why assert_called_once_with() is expecting the actual parameter that's called.
Here is the relevant section in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#any

EDIT:
The make_patch_call() ultimately calls this patch function after computing all the parameters needed for the patch function.

```
def patch(self, url, payload, callback=None, async_run=False, **kwargs):
    payload = self._serialize_payload(payload)
    func = self._do_async_request if async_run else self._do_request
    return func('patch', (url, payload), callback, kwargs)
```

Comment: It should work if the calls match. Can you show your actual call (e.g. what `make_patch_call` actually does)?

Comment: sure, I've added the patch function that's called

Comment: The problem seems to be the `kwargs` argument, that In the call is the argument `svc_auth`. This will not work - the arguments must match (e.g. if you substitute `kwargs` with `svc_auth`, it may work). I understand the intention, but I don't think it is possible to match `args` or `kwargs` this way.

Comment: Great, specifying the value of kwargs worked! If you write an official answer to this question, I'll select it as the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `assert_called_with`, the arguments and the used keywords have to exactly match. Substituting an argument for `ANY` will always match the argument value, but the keyword must still match the used keyword. The generic keywords `args` and `kwargs` are no exception: if you expect them, they have to be used in the call to match.

In this case, the `kwargs` keyword in the expected call:

```py
mock_patch.assert_called_with(url=ANY, payload=ANY, callback=ANY, async_run=ANY, kwargs=ANY)
```

has to be changed to the really used keyword `svc_auth`:

```py
mock_patch.assert_called_with(url=ANY, payload=ANY, callback=ANY, async_run=ANY, svc_auth=ANY)
```

Note that the same applies for keyword versus positional arguments, which is a common pitfall. If you have a function `foo(bar)`, then you have to expect the call exactly as it is made, e.g:

```py
@mock.patch("my_module.foo")
def test_foo(patched):
    foo(42)
    patched.assert_called_with(ANY)  # passes
    patched.assert_called_with(bar=ANY)  # fails

    foo(bar=42)
    patched.assert_called_with(ANY)  # fails
    patched.assert_called_with(bar=ANY)  # passes
```